# How to compute the intersection of the ideals $(x-y, z-w)$ and $(x-z, y-w)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $k[x,y,z,w]$ be a polynomial ring generated by $x,y,z,w$. Let $I_1=(x-y, z-w)$ and $I_2=(x-z, y-w)$. How to compute the generator of the ideal $I_1 \cap I_2$? I think that $I_1 \cap I_2 \neq ( (x-y)(x-z), (x-y)(y-w), (z-w)(x-z), (z-w)(y-w) )$. We need to add some more elements to $( (x-y)(x-z), (x-y)(y-w), (z-w)(x-z), (z-w)(y-w) )$. How to find these elements? Thank you very much.

Comment: [This is a general algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis#Intersecting_ideals)

Comment: $I_1\cap I_2$ contains $x-y-z+w$. In the factor ring $k[x,y,z,w]/(x-y-z+w)\simeq K[x,y,z]$ we have $I_1\cap I_2=(x-y)\cap(x-z)=((x-y)(x-z))$. Thus $I_1\cap I_2=(x-y-z+w,(x-y)(x-z))$.

Comment: @user26857, thank you very much. How to show that $I_1 \cap I_2$ contains $x-y-z+w$?

Comment: $x-y-z+w=(x-y)-(z-w)\in I_1$ and $=(x-z)-(y-w)\in I_2$.